# HTML elements not visible after changing them with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a table wich looks like this:

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Gerät</th>
            <th>Zugriff</th>
            <th>Raum</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr id="1">
             <td>Lampe</td>
             <td>hier kommt der zugriff rein</td>
             <td>1</td><td><button onclick="bearbeiten(1)">bearbeiten</button></td>
             <td><button onclick="loeschen(1)">löschen</button></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

After you click the button which triggers the function "bearbeiten". It is supposed to rewrite the table row like this:

```
<tr id="1">
    <form action="action/aendern.php">
        <td><input type="text" value="Lampe"></td>
        <td><input type="text" value="hier kommt der zugriff rein"></td>
        <td><input type="text" value="1"></td>
        <td><input type="text" value="bearbeiten"></td>
        <td><input type="text" value="löschen"></td>
        <td><input type="submit" value="Ändern"></td>
    </form>
</tr>
```

**It does change it like that. However, You can not see it.**

I tried adding exactly that, what it was changed to, to the table and it worked great. But why won't it be visible, if Javascript changes it?

This is my function:

```
function bearbeiten(id) {
        let tr = document.getElementById(id);
        
    // Erstellen eines neuen <form> Elements
    let form = document.createElement("form");
    form.setAttribute("action", "action/aendern.php");
    
    // Durchlaufen der <td> Elemente in der ausgewählten Zeile und Erstellen von <input> Elementen
    tr.querySelectorAll("td").forEach(function(td, index) {
        let input = document.createElement("input");
        input.setAttribute("type", "text");
        input.setAttribute("value", td.textContent.trim()); // Den aktuellen Textinhalt als Standardwert verwenden
        let newTd = document.createElement("td");
        newTd.appendChild(input);
        form.appendChild(newTd);
    });
    
    // Erstellen eines Submit-Buttons
    let submitButton = document.createElement("input");
    submitButton.setAttribute("type", "submit");
    submitButton.setAttribute("value", "Ändern");
    let buttonTd = document.createElement("td");
    buttonTd.appendChild(submitButton);
    form.appendChild(buttonTd);
    
    // Ersetzen der Zeile mit dem neuen <form> Element
    tr.innerHTML = ""; // Zeile leeren
    tr.appendChild(form);
}
```

Comment: A `<form>` as a child of `<tr>` is invalid HTML.  In my browser there's a user agent style rule that prevents that form from displaying, any other browser may have any other way of handling the same scenario.  But the first thing you'd need to do is start with valid markup.